# iOS: Why is Facebook logout button is not displayed properly?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate Facebook login into my iOS app (using XCode 6+ and Deployment Target is iOS 7.0). I have placed a normal UIButton to my ViewController in the storyboard and changed to custom class with FBSDKLoginButton since I needed the button in slight bigger size than originally.

The login process works great and the login button image is shown perfectly, but after login the button changes to "logout" and the background seems transparent with some strange white rectangle behind.

Here's an illustration of the issue:

[image]

**Somebody any idea what I am doing wrong ?**

Comment: Can you reproduce this with any of the samples as part of the SDK? Also which iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: Hi Shireesh, sorry for the late reply. I am using FB SDK version 4.2.0 (latest version). I could not reproduce the error with the "Scrumptious" sample app from the FB-SDK bundle...

Comment: Hmm... using an UIView as base instead of a UIButton works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue using an UIButton, but I changed it to an UIView and it is working perfectly. Probably go with that approach, or implement a custom button (Objective-C)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/advanced#custom-login-button

Comment: You can use UIButton with type "Custom" (instead "System"). It's working for me (in Xcode 7, iOS 9)

Comment: @ДаниилГеоргиевич 's is correct, this is what I did, works like a charm even in iOS10

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when i used the storyboard to implement the FaceBook login and logout button.
You have just to drag a view to your view controller and add custom class for this view named "FBSDKLoginButton" then set it to a clear background.

Comment: Sami20722 : Is correct this works with Swit 2.0 Xcode 7.2. Thanks @Sami

Answer (score 0):

While you have the Login "button" selected in your document outline panel, open up the attributes inspector and select any image below "Shadow Color" and above "Background" (this doesn't show up, it's just a placeholder). Next, open up the size inspector and adjust the size of the facebook button. My facebook button is on the right side of my navigation bar and following the above steps solved this problem for me.